# What can SIM applets do?

Tags: android, applet, sim-toolkit

Is there any paper that describes the capability of SIM applets?

I want to know what SIM applets can do and what permissions they have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [3GPP 31.111 document](https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=1807) which describes all the proactive commands which an STK applet can use (as far as the ME supports them).

Another interesting API is the [SIMalliance Open Mobile API](http://simalliance.org/se/se-technical-releases/simalliance-open-mobile-api-archive/) which allows applications installed in the phone to communicate with the (U)SIM/SE applets (as long as the phone supports this API).

Answer (score 2):

Some solutions that can be realized by using SIM applets :

- Dynamic SIM Toolkit menu which assists MNO subscriber with services such as; balance, package usage query, tariff plan changes, package purchases, money transfer
- Mobile Payment SIM application, since the SIM is the secure element it can keep credit/debit card information securely according to PCI standards and you can carry out payments via payment gateways with PIN code without using your real card.
- Coverage monitoring SIM application, SIM applet can register several event types to terminal(location update, access technology changes, call drops). When the event occurs, terminal fires the callback and SIM applet can report it to backend through SMS or IP bearer(sending data via IP requires that SIM should support using IP bearer)
- M2M applications. If M2M device supports special proactive commands for different type of measurements, applet can collect those measurements and send it to backend applications.
- Tracking M2M device location,automatic switching between available networks. Fallback between available bearer channels.